# What will be the corresponding structure of if..else in MIPS?

Tags: if-statement, assembly, mips, mips32

Given the general construct of if..else in C as

```
    if(cond) {
        block_if};
    else {
        block_else};
```

what will be the corresponding structure of if_else in MIPS?

Comment: One or more conditional branches.

Comment: [MIPS if greater or equals to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57996725) is a good canonical answer about how to construct an `if` or `if/else` from conditional branches.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an *if-else* control structure in MIPS.

It's just a branch instruction to jump to the `else` label if the condition is false. Otherwise, it continues, executes the *if*'s body, and then jumps to the `end` label.

After that jump instruction is the `else` label, followed by the else's body, and then the `end` label.

The code in the *if*'s body executes only if the condition is true, and the code in the *else*'s body only executes if the condition is false.

```
# $t0 = cond
beq $t0,$zero,else
# if(cond) {
# Do code
j end
# } else {
else:
# Do code
# }
end:
```