# Why is the loop not updating properly?

Tags: assembly, arm64

```
define(x_r, x18)        // Defines X
define(y_r, x19)        // Defines Y
define(ymin, x20)       // Sets the Minimum of Y

define(a_r, x21)        // Defines a in ax^3
define(b_r, x22)        // Defines b in bx^2
define(c_r, x23)        // Defines c in cx
define(d_r, x24)        // Defines the constant

define(w_r, x25)        // Defines x^2
define(t_r, x26)        // Defines x^3

setup:
    .output: .string "X = %d, Y = %d Current Minimum of Y is: %d\n"
    .balign 4
    .global main
main:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
    mov x29, sp

    mov ymin, 0x7fffffffffffffff      // Current minimum of Y
    mov x_r, -10            // Sets x to -10
    mov a_r, 3              // a = 3
    mov b_r, 31             // b = 31
    mov c_r, -15            // c = -15
    mov d_r, -127           // d = -127

Loop:
    mul w_r, x_r, x_r                  // Makes w_r into x^2
    mul t_r, w_r, x_r                  // Makes t_r into x^3

    mov y_r, 0                          // Sets Y to 0 for the Loop
    add y_r, y_r, d_r                   // y = -127
    madd y_r, x_r, c_r, y_r             // y = -15x - 127
    madd y_r, b_r, w_r, y_r             // y = 31x^2 - 15x - 127
    madd y_r, a_r, t_r, y_r             // y = 3x^3 + 31x^2 - 15x - 127

    cmp y_r, ymin
    b.lt update_minimum

update_minimum:
    mov ymin, y_r
    b Print

Print:
    adrp x0, .output
    add x0, x0, :lo12: .output
    mov x1, x_r
    mov x2, y_r
    mov x3, ymin

    bl printf

loop_check:
    add x_r, x_r, 1                       // Increment X (x18)
    cmp x_r, 5                            // Check if x < 5
    b.lt Loop

end:
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], 16
    ret
```

Short and to point I am trying to get this to display X, Y and the current minimum Y, however, for some reason, the minimum Y value just copies the current Y instead. I suspect something is bugged out with how the minimum is calculated but so far I keep getting the same result.

I have tried editing the Order of events to see if label was missed, however the same thing kept happening. I also tried to push the initial Y minimum outside of the loop to see if anything would change. Then I created the update_minimum label as well to try and fix it. At this point I really don't see where the bug would be since my logic seems pretty accurate. Can someone help me point out what I'm not seeing?

Comment: Did you check the calling convention to make sure x18-26 are all call-preserved?  `bl printf` will modify all the call-clobbered registers.

Comment: `b.lt update_minimum` goes to the next instruction whether the condition was true (jump there) or false (fall through to there).  Jump somewhere else if you don't want `mov ymin, y_r` to execute.  Same bug as [Code executes condition wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32872539) (but that's about x86), Or [What will be the corresponding structure of if..else in MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39783738) for MIPS, also showing how to use conditional branches (like an if()goto) to build an if/else or just an if.

Comment: Labels don't execute: the processor doesn't even see them. They don't section off parts of code, only control flow changes which parts of code get executed.

Comment: [How do labels execute in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66012557) covers that in the general ISA-neutral case.

Comment: I changed it to "cmp y_r, ymin b.gt loop_check" but now it only displays the values where the minimum changes (x= -10, -3, -2, -1, 0)

Comment: Yes, that's what you'd expect.  If you want to just skip the `mov`, put a label after it and conditionally branch then when you want it to not run.  Or since this is AArch64, the easy solution in this case is `csel` instead of `mov` to conditionally-select according to a condition.

Comment: [MIPS if greater or equals to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57996725) is a good canonical answer about how to construct an `if` or `if/else` from conditional branches, with plenty of text description of why you do it that way.